# responsive height of div

Tags: html, css

Working on a angular website using bootstrap and encountered a small issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      random text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.content {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I want the `.content` div to take up the full screensize, nothing more nothing less. However I already have a header element (fixed size 60px) above it so using 100vh will make it slightly more than the whole screensize (screensize+header).

How can I format my css in such a way that the `.content` div will always have a height of exactly the screen size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `CSS calc()` function to `minus` the `header height` which is `60px` from `.content` height as below,

> The calc() CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying
>   CSS property values.

```
.content {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px); /*Add this*/
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  height: 60px; /* Take this value and mius below using calc()*/
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px); /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>Header</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      random text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)

```
  .content {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use calc();
see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc or https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

```
<style>
    #myDiv {
       width: 100vw;
       height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
</style>
<body><div id="myDiv"></body>
```